# Spring Boot Application shown as UNKNOWN in Eureka server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm running an application with Spring (as Discovery Client app), also have a Discovery Server with Eureka, and Spring Cloud Config Server. When the client app is started it's registered as "UNKNOWN" in Eureka, despite its status is set to"UP", isn't able to get the properties from the configuration server.

**Client App, Eureka server,and Config Server Spring Boot Version: 2.4.2**

**Client bootstrap.properties:**

```
spring.application.name=config-client-app
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}
```

**Client application.properties file:**

```
logging.level.=debug
server.port=8900
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
```

**Client Application Class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class ConfigClientAppApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigClientAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Eureka Serverproperties file:**

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Eureka Application class:**

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**The log info:**

```
restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
2021-02-09 16:02:50.388  INFO 2845 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1612904570388 with initial instances count: 1
2021-02-09 16:02:50.390  INFO 2845 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application UNKNOWN with eureka with status UP
2021-02-09 16:02:50.391  INFO 2845 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1612904570391, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2021-02-09 16:02:50.391  INFO 2845 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/192.168.10.22:8900: registering service...
2021-02-09 16:02:50.391  WARN 2845 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : Ignoring onDemand update due to rate limiter
2021-02-09 16:02:50.393  INFO 2845 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8900 (http) with context path ''
2021-02-09 16:02:50.394  INFO 2845 --- [  restartedMain] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8900
2021-02-09 16:02:50.413  INFO 2845 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/192.168.10.22:8900 - registration status: 204
```

Comment: can you show the versions?

Comment: All apps were created using Spring Boot Version 2.4.2

Comment: I don't believe bootstrap.properties can use ${...} references since those come from the application.properties and the bootstrap is loaded before the app.properties. What happens when you set eureka.instance.instance-id=client?

Comment: @Zack Already tried that, with the same result.

Comment: By default (without knowing your dependencies) bootstrap is no longer read in spring cloud 2020.0. Either move the configuration to application.properties or add spring cloud starter bootstrap

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring cloud version

```
<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
```

and spring boot version

```
<version>2.7.5</version>
```

In application.properties, add the following lines to resolve the error:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

By default, the Eureka Server registers itself into the discovery. The following 2 lines will tell eureka server that there is only one eureka server present in this context.

in the absence of these, our Eureka Server will try to find and register itself on other Eureka Servers in the context and throw a discovery client exception. i.e our own system.

> If you encounter the below errors after adding the above properties only you need to add the below properties.

We must add this to the `properties`, if configuration is not required.

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

Otherwise application will throw below exception.

```
No spring.config.import property has been defined
```

(or) If you have a other server, such as any configuration server we can add this optional server configuration to  `application.properties`,

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver: Your server url
```

> Spring Cloud Config provides server and client-side support for
> externalized configuration in a distributed system

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Move spring.application.name=config-client-app in application.properties, not in bootstrap.properties.
I had the same issue.